# Sort rows in the same order specified in MySQL IN()

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Have some IDs:

```
$ids = "'55-30269','50-30261','50-30254','50-30257','50-30268','50-30253'";
```

Have this query:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `report` WHERE `id` IN ($ids)";
```

I want the rows to be in the same order like specified in `$ids`.
Instead of that I get order by which these rows were originally inserted in table.

Also, i'm not sure why do I need each of id to be placed in quotes `'55-30269'`, but query is not getting executed other way. E.g. `$ids = "55-30269,50-30261,50-30254,50-30257,50-30268,50-30253";`

Comment: You will need to use quotes otherwise you will only match first two number before `-`

Comment: [`FIELD(str,str1,str2,str3,...)`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_field) or [`FIND_IN_SET(str,strlist)`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) comes to mind.

Comment: @M8R-1jmw5r `FIELD()` :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because the data type of `ID` is string. String literals must be wrap with single quotes. If you want to order the result based on the specified `ID`, use `FIELD()` for custom reordering.

```
SELECT  *
FROM    report
WHERE   ID IN ($ids)
ORDER   BY FIELD(ID, $ids)
```

- [FIELD()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_field)

The reason why you are not getting exact result when passing ID without single quotes,

```
$ids = "55-30269,50-30261,50-30254,50-30257,50-30268,50-30253"
```

is because MySQL performs arithmetic on the values.

```
55-30269 = -30216
50-30261 = -30211
...
```